# ICollection not displaying in view mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Everything else displaying in my view except ICollection.

Tes Model

```
    public class Tes
    {
        [Key]
        public int tID { get; set; }

        public int FromUserID { get; set; }//user logged in
        public int ToUserId { get; set; } //user to be sent
        public int itemTId { get; set; } //single item

        public virtual ICollection<Item> items { get; set; }

    }
```

Item Model

```
    public class Item
    {

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string item_name { get; set; }
    public string item_description { get; set; }
    public string item_code { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateAdded { get; set; }
    public int catId { get; set; }
    public int?  isSelected { get; set; }
    public int isQuick { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tes> tes{ get; set; }

    }

public class ItemDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ItemDBContext()
        : base("name=ItemDbContext")
    { }

    public DbSet <Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Cats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tes> Tes{ get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tes>().HasMany(e => e.items).WithMany(e => e.tes);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Tes take)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Trades.Add(take);

            //do I add ICollection seperately?

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(take);
    }
```

View

```
     @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ToUserId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemTId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.items)//not displaying?
    </td>
```

Ajax POST

```
        var take= {
    FromUserID: uid,
    ToUserID: TradeeUid,
    itemTradedForId: TradeeItemId,
    items: ids,
    __RequestVerificationToken: $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val()
}

//jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Trade/Create",
    data: take
    //dataType:JSON
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //data: JSON.stringify(take)

  });
```

this is what I get.

[image: ICollection not displaying]

If I try to get at the `items` from a nested for loop. I get an error

[image]

Fixed that with:

[image]

but still no `ICollection` displaying. Could it be they are not being stored?

Comment: 'Item' is not a primitive type. How do you imagine DisplayFor should interpret it? What should It show?
The framework can do a lot for you, but no magic :)

Comment: @Mvision item displays everything else though. How to access this ICollection then?

Comment: @Mvision LOL. Wouldn't life be so much easier if the framework had a Magic nuget package to install? Maybe MVC 5.

Comment: items are null. That's the problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `DisplayFor` works like that. You have to iterate through each individual item as such.

```
@foreach (var tes in Model) {
  ...
  @foreach (var item in tes.items) {
    Html.DisplayFor(m => m.item_name)
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: oh I see. Let me test

Comment: I'm wrong. The problem is I can't get at the `item` properties